# Visual studio Error The command copy /Y

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2015, build, msbuild

I have following statements in some of my projects

```
copy /Y "$(TargetDir)*.dll" "$(SolutionDir)MyMainDirectory.WebServices\bin\"
```

Occasionally i am getting error like :

```
The command "copy /Y "D:\MyApp1\bin\Release\*.dll" "D:\MyMainDirectory.WebServices\bin\"" exited with code 1.
```

Further digging down i have by changing `MSBuild` project build output verbosity I see error like :

```
The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process.
```

Any idea how to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i have mentioned it is due to parallel building of project which are trying to use same library what i have did is set maximum number of parallel projects build to 1. Now i am not getting that error

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution here :), that is great!

Answer (score 1):

> Visual studio Error The command copy /Y

The error `The command...exited with code 1` does not match your detailed error message `The process ...being used by another process.`. If the file is used by another process, the command should give the error `Unable to copy file...`, so, the reason in the detailed log may not be the cause of the failure of the command execution.

According to the error log "exited with code 1", it specify that this command is incorrect. And I have checked this command, the syntax of copy is correct, so the problem is the path is not incorrect or the destination folder is read only, you need check if the destination folder exists and attributes.

For the detailed error, you can use [ProcessExplorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to find out what process has the file open and go from there.

If a process is currently using those DLL, you can't delete and re-write it. You'll have to kill or otherwise stop the process using those DLLs while you compile.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What i have a plugin architecture where different dll can be added at run time. Problem is that on code solution i have them at one solution and during compilation looks like they are using common dlls

Comment: @KamranShahid, Thanks for your reply. Since you have plugin using this common dlls, I am afraid you have to solve the problem of process occupation. Or you can create a new project out of your plugin architecture, then add this copy command.